# sql pivoting/transpose rows by creating multiple columns from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like below. There can be any number rows per customer. The columns Cust_ID, Decision, Name, Order_Id is Unique for each customer. I am trying to achieve 1 row per cust_id by pivoting last 2 columns Order_Name and Order_Amt

```
Cust_ID  Decision  Name   Order_ID  Order_Name   Order_Amt
1       Ordered   ABC         123        A1           10    
1       Ordered   ABC         123        A2           20
1       Ordered   ABC         123        A3           30
1       Ordered   ABC         123        A4           40  

2       Decline   DEF         456        L1           30    
2       Decline   DEF         456        L2           40
```

Result I am looking is:

```
Cust_ID   Decision  Name    Order_ID    Order_Name_1    Order_Name_2    Order_Name_3    Order_Name_4   Order_Amt_1  Order_Amt_2     Order_Amt_3     Order_Amt_4
1       Ordered     ABC         123        A1             A2            A3              A4        10                20                 30                40       
2       Decline     DEF         456        L1             L2            NULL            NULL           30           40                  NULL            NULL
```

What I tried is

```
select cust_id, Decision, Name, Order_Name,
 max( case when Decision = 'Ordered' and Order_Name = 'A1' then 'A1' end) as Order_Name1
```

There are other pivot examples I referred, but all that i found is creating column names from the rows

Comment: Missing specifications: How many rows per `Cust_ID`? I see a maximum of 4. Be specific. How big is the table? Table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), Postgres version (`SELECT version();`).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have updated the comments

Comment: *"Any number of rows per customer"* is too vague. Would you want a table with 10000 columns? Plain SQL can only deliver a *fixed* number of columns. You might need dynamic SQL or two round trips ... And I had more requests in my first comment.

Comment: what i meant is there could be different number of rows for different customers. max number of rows per customer can be assumed as 10

Comment: The rest of my requests seem to be invisible. I can look away, too.

Comment: So what happens when a customer places their 11th order? Do you reject the order? Do you delete the 1st (oldest order)?  Does your system crash or fail to provide complete accurate results? Point is you **cannot assume**, you must handle the situation.  Basically, this is not a task suited for database but better left to your presentation manager. (Yes SQL can be make to do limited pivoting, but that does not mean it is the proper place for it.)